# Configure proxy settings for requests encapsulated by cs in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, encapsulation

For example in the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library you can set proxy configuration [explicitely](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#module-requests).

With [exoscale/cs](https://github.com/exoscale/cs/blob/master/cs/client.py) (a Python client for Apache Cloud Stack) it does not work for me.

Environment variables are set correctly to locally meaningful values accepted locally in other contexts:

```
'http_proxy': 'x.x.x.x:nnn'
```

Error:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='yyyy', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /portal/client
```

Observations so far:

- Host to connect is yyyy:443
- Proxy is xxxx:nnn (xxxxx is a valid DNS name)
- Requests' error is a ProxyError but as message might be read, tries to connect to target hosts directly?
- Wait, it seems like `cs` incorporates `requests`!

How to tell the encapsulated `requests` to to use proxy?

Comment: your code is same as this? `proxies ={"https":"x.x.x.x:yyy"}`

Comment: how do you mean @kcorlidy? `x.x.x.x` in your example suggests to take an IP address; I have `xxxx` i.e. a valid DNS name. I tried to create a global Python variable `proxies` following your example but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, requesrts **does** parse OS environment variables.

```
% export http_proxy="http://hello.test"                                
% python -c "import urllib.request; print(urllib.request.getproxies())"
{'http': 'http://hello.test'}
```